# Product related widget like price slider not working in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements

In my website no product related widget working on theme/woocomerce/archive-product.php.

On the archive product page I write following code:

```
if(is_shop()){
echo 'shop page'; 
} else{
echo 'not shop page'; 
}
exit;
```

It says 'not shop page'. I cant figure out what make archive-product not shop page in woocommerce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a documentation regarding [Woocommerce conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/).

For archive pages on woocommerce:

- Shop pages: `is_shop()`
- Product category pages : `is_product_category()`
- Product Tag pages: `is_product_tag()`

You can test with:

```
if ( is_shop() ) {
    echo 'Shop page'; 
} elseif ( is_product_category() ) {
    echo 'Product category page'; 
} elseif ( is_product_tag() ) {
    echo 'Product Tag page'; 
} else {
    echo 'not an archive page'; 
}
exit;
```

Comment: It says "Product category page". What could be the problem that no product related widget working?

Comment: I just see the price filter(slider) working for simple product not variable product. Is there something I can do?

Thank you sir.